# interview omission

Tags: interviewing

I am trying to get a job abroad for aprox. 1 year, In may I received an offer from an employer in my town. the job was a good opportunity if I remain in my town and country. still, I would like to keep an eye on the jobs abroad and keep applying. this is why I applied for a job abroad and had a first interview this week. the interview was good, I have a good feeling, but I did not mentioned that for one month I started at another job. I was blocked somehow at the moment when, maybe it would have been the moment to mention. I think I was afraid not to be misunderstood because I apply for a new job after one month, or that I accepted a job knowing that my dream is to move abroad. Can you please advise how to deal with this situation if I am invited to a second interview? I am not comfortable with this situation and I would like to clarify this with professionalism. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you get the just abroad i'd take that over everything else.  Simple explain to your current employer that you've found an opportunity that you can't turn down and thank them for everything, etc. etc.

Comment: career advice is off topic, voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm understanding you correctly, you interviewed with a company at home and got a job offer that you accepted. The issue is that you want to work abroad, and you just had your first interview with a company in a different country.

If this is the case:

Have you signed any contracts for the local company? If not, you're still able to change your mind and back out of the job. **However**, it should be handled delicately, or you risk burning bridges. Doing this will likely guarantee you will never get hired again at this company, so consider it carefully.

It sounds as if your primary worry is about the abroad employer, though. You do **not** need to inform them that you have accepted another offer, especially if you'd prefer to work for the foreign company. If you really feel like you need to tell them something, just inform them that you have received another offer from a different company; sometimes this can be a useful bargaining chip when it comes to salary negotiations.